# How can you modify the results in semantic `ui search` module

Tags: semantic-ui

So I am trying to display custom results of my search API to the `results` div appropriately.

I am aware that the results need to have a key in the result objects called `title` to show by default, but is there a way to tell it what `key` in the results object to display?

Or better yet is there a way to stylize or customize the results that are shown? After that how can I get the object that was selected?

The API's response and communications are working fine.

This is what I have so far:

[image: This is what I have so far]

Comment: you linked to a ".png" !?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the callback onResultsOpen and within iterate each result with
`$('.result').each(function(){//do stuff to the result here})`

Worked for me (had the same question which brought me here)

Comment: onResultsOpen  is a callback when the results dropdown is shown and has nothing to do with handling the response from the server. Based on the OP's picture it seems the response JSON object is not properly formatted

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI's API examples show how to modify the results. There is actually [an example](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#modifying-response-json) made with `.ui.search`. Just to give an idea, you have to get the parameter passed to onResponse, modify it as you with and return the modified version of it.

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
    minCharacters : 3,
    apiSettings   : {
      url        : 'api.yousearchservice.com/{query}',
      onResponse : function(theresponse) {
         // here you modify theresponse object,
         // then you return the modified version.
         return theresponse
      }
   });
```

Comment: is it onResponse? I've tried returning the new formatted response in onResults and onResponse but its not working.

Comment: @Daskul see my answer, yes it is onResponse - make sure you assign the fields correctly in the options - See their documentation they have a good example

Answer (score 1):

You can set the structure of your results server side then handle the rest in the AJAX response :

E.g Fetch cities from DB

```
$results = array();
foreach($cities as $city){         
   $results['items'][] = array(
         'name' =>  $city->name,
         'country' => $city->country,
         'currency' => $city->currency,
         'url' => '...' // could be the ActionURL for Semantic 
           );
     }
return response()->json($results, 200); // return as JSON
```

then in you Javascript you just need to loop thourgh `$results['items']` and assign the corresponding [fields](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/settings), categories ect..

```
$('.ui.search')
.search({
    apiSettings: {
        url: 'URL?q={query}',
        onResponse: function (citiesResponse) {
            var response = { // response as the items on the front-end
                results: {}
                };

            // here citiesResponse.items = $results['items']
            $.each(citiesResponse.items, function (index, item) {

                // here country = Category if you wish to have the results in that format
                var country = item.country.toUpperCase() || 'Unknown',
                    maxResults = 15;

                if (index >= maxResults) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (response.results[country] === undefined) {
                    response.results[country] = {
                        name: country,
                        results: []
                    };
                }
                response.results[country].results.push({
                    title: item.name, // $results['items'][]['name']
                    description: item.currency, // $results['items'][]['currency']
                    url: item.url  // ActionURL when item is clicked  $results['items'][]['url']
                });
            });
            return response;
        }
    },
    // define custom fields
    fields: {
        results: 'results',
        title: 'title',
        category: 'country',
        actionURL: "url"
    },
    type: 'category',
    cache: true,
    minCharacters: 3,
    searchDelay: 1000
});
```

Their website documentation is [self-explanatory](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples) . If you want more flexibility for example instead of adding all fields within the `description` field you can instead create a custom template.